# Getting webpack and webpack dev server to work for HMR

Tags: webpack, react-hot-loader

I have my `webpack.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8090', // WebpackDevServer host and port
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // "only" prevents reload on syntax errors
        './public/js/app.jsx' // Your appʼs entry point
    ],
    debug: true,
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: filelocation,
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/',
        hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/[id].[hash].hot-update.js',
        hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/[hash].hot-update.json'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            // test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loaders: ['react-hot','babel?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=react'],
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/js"),
            ],
            exclude: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
            ]
        }],
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
        }
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]

};
```

when I run `webpack --watch` it perfectly works fine. As when I make changes it produces the `hot-update.js`/`json` under my `hot` directory.

And I have my webpack dev server, which looks like this:

```
new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    hot: true,
}).listen(8090, 'localhost', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I run `webpack --watch` and webpack dev server paralley. I could able to make a change and webpack is pushing the changes to `hot` directory. But on my browser console, webpack development server is throwing error like:

```
 http://localhost:8090/hot/8f052261dd06c76e85cd.hot-update.json 404
[HMR] Cannot find update. Need to do a full reload!
[HMR] (Probably because of restarting the webpack-dev-server)
```

when I reload it works. Note that manually the above url:

```
http://localhost:8090/hot/8f052261dd06c76e85cd.hot-update.json
```

is accessible. Not sure where I'm making the mistake. Also is there a way to not save the hot son/js files on disk but just send only to web pack-dev-server, which applies the HMR?

Webpack and webpack-dev-server versions are greater than `1.7.0`

Comment: Running just `WebpackDevServer` should be enough. Did you add `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` plugin?

Comment: Running only `WebpackDevServer` doesn't throw error for the hot replacement files (since I have configured `publicpath`)? Yeah I do have the plugin, sorry now I have edited the question